# http://modules.sourceforge.net/ alternative

Tags: module

Do you know a alternative to [module](http://modules.sourceforge.net/)?

I really like load/unloading with it, but I feel writting the modulefile is tedious.

I'm especially interessed if a Python alternative exists. Searching on the web is difficult due to the "python module" keywords...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a **lua**-based module system named **Lmod** (first release in 2008)

http://www.tacc.utexas.edu/tacc-projects/mclay/lmod

http://sourceforge.net/projects/lmod/

Just for the record I also found an old project called **cmod** written in **C**
(latest release in September 1998)

http://www.lysator.liu.se/cmod/